# Will ls always list the files that rm will remove?

Tags: bash, 18.04, ls, rm, hidden-files

Something I feel I ought to know for sure: if I `ls <something>`, will `rm <something>` remove exactly the same files that `ls` displayed? Are there any circumstances where `rm` could remove files that `ls` did not show? (This is in the 18.04 bash)

Edit: thank you to everyone who answered. I think the full answer is a combination of all the answers, so I have accepted the most up-voted answer as "the answer".

Unexpected things I have learned along the way:

- `ls` is not as straightforward as you might think in its handling of its arguments
- In a simple un-fiddled-with installation of Ubuntu, .bashrc aliases `ls`
- Don't name your files beginning with a dash as they can look like command arguments, and naming one -r is asking for it!

Comment: That is why you don't use ls and rm but find with the delete option.  Something like `find . -name * -delete`  to remove all files in the current directory.

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that `rm` does not have a `--dry-run` flag...

Comment: @Rinzwind Why would `find -delete` be better than `rm`? You say _"That is why"_, but it's completely unclear to me what that refers to. Also note that your `find` invocation will delete all files *recursively* in the current directory, where `rm` will just delete the files in the immediate directory. Also `-name *` is a no-op. All in all, I'm quite puzzled by your advice...

Comment: @marcelm I think the advice for using `find` is because you can run it, see all the files, and then run the same command with `-delete`. Since you already saw the results from `find`, there should be no ambiguity to what will be removed (I'd actually like to hear more details about this in the form of an answer)

Comment: Because find feeds the delete the file it needs to remove. That solves choroba's answer for instant where a file is created after ls and before rm. and do mind the "something like" It is pseudo code.

Comment: @Scribblemacher _"... you can run it, see all the files, and then run the same command with `-delete`"_ - But how is that better than running `ls <filespec>`, followed by `rm <filespec>` (which the OP already knows how to do)?

Comment: @Rinzwind _"That solves choroba's answer for instant where a file is created after ls and before rm."_ - No, it doesn't. If you run `find ... -print` first to confirm what files would be deleted, and then `find ... -delete`, you'll still delete files created between the two commands. If you use both `-print` and `-delete`, you don't get confirmation, just an after-the-fact report of what has been deleted (and you might as well use `rm -v`).

Comment: @Rinzwind Not necessarily. `find` still builds up a data structure first, then processes it. If it's just one file, it's instant, but not for recursive and multifile cases.

Comment: @fkralem how about `rm -i`?

Comment: @fkraiem `rm` *does* have a dry-run flag: `-i`

Comment: @dessert No, `-i` is for `i`nteractive: it prompts you before each file to be removed. A `--dry-run` flag would non-interactively print a list of files that would be removed in a normal run.

Comment: @fkraiem But that wouldn’t cover files created between the two calls, which probably is why the developers decided to implement it this way instead.

Comment: @dessert That's irrelevant. Many other commands have a similar flag, and it would do exactly what OP wants to do with `ls`.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned symbolic links; you'll get [very different](https://askubuntu.com/a/1072875/128097) results when you pass a symlink as the argument to `ls` and `rm`.

Comment: "naming one -r is asking for it". I'd say from the point of the file owner - yes. But from the point of view of shell script author or system admin, sometimes you've no way but to deal with it and you can't go around renaming files ( try to rename a file owned by your supervisor, see how they respond ). That's why when using `*` it's recommended to use `./*` or `--` if available (and on some, especially non-GNU implementations of commands) that `--` flag is not available.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well, both `ls` and `rm` operate on the arguments which are passed to them.

These arguments can be a simple file, so `ls file.ext` and `rm file.ext` operate on the same file and the outcome is clear (list the file / delete the file).

If instead argument is a directory, `ls directory` lists the *content* of the directory while `rm directory` won't work as is (i.e. `rm` without flags cannot remove directories, while if you do `rm -r directory`, it recursively deletes *all files* under `directory` **and the directory itself**).

But keep in mind that command line arguments can be subjected to *shell expansion*,
so it's not *always guaranteed* that the same arguments are passed to both commands
if they contain wildcards, variables, output from other commands, etc.

As an extreme example think `ls $(rand).txt` and `rm $(rand).txt`, the arguments are "the same" but the results are quite different!

Comment: Also consider `ls` vs `rm *` where there are "hidden" (dot) files, though even that's not at all a fair comparison as I didn't write `ls *`. But `rm` is meaningless on its own so the entire thing is apples and oranges really. If I've understood correctly, that's the crux of your answer, so good job :)

Comment: Another comment on `ls` vs `rm -r`: the command `ls <directory>` will not show hidden files inside the directory, but `rm -r <directory>` *will* delete even the hidden files.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `ls` won't list them (unless it's aliased to `ls -a`), and `rm *` won't delete them (unless you have `dotglob` set).

Answer (score 21):

If you're thinking of something like `ls foo*.txt` vs. `rm foo*.txt`, then yes, they will show and remove the same files. The shell expands the glob, and passes it to the command in question, and the commands work on the listed files. One listing them, one removing them.

The obvious difference is that if any of those files happened to be a directory, then `ls` would list its contents, but `rm` would fail to remove it. That's usually not a problem, since `rm` would remove *less* than what was shown by `ls`.

**The big issue here comes from** running `ls *` or `rm *` in a directory containing **filenames starting with a dash**. They would expand to the command lines of the two programs as if you wrote them out yourself, and `ls` would take `-r` to mean "reverse sort order", while `rm` would take `-r` to mean a recursive removal. The difference matters if you have subdirectories at least two levels deep. (`ls *` will show the contents of the first level directories, but `rm -r *` will everything past the first sublevel, too.)

To avoid that, write permissive globs with a leading `./` to indicate the current directory, and/or put a `--` to signal the end of option processing before the glob (i.e. `rm ./*` or `rm -- *`).

With a glob like `*.txt`, that's actually not an issue since the dot is an invalid option character, and will cause an error (until someone expands the utilities to invent a meaning for it), but it's still safer to put the `./` there anyway.

---

Of course you could also get different results for the two commands if you changed the shell's globbing options, or created/moved/removed files in between the commands, but I doubt you meant any of those cases. (Dealing with new/moved files would be extremely messy to do safely.)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to highlight an issue with the whole command line syntax: if you name files starting with a dash you are sailing in dangerous waters. Who knows what commands you might use in the future, long after you've forgotten about the - files.

Comment: @B.Tanner, yes. In a sense, the problem is that the command line arguments are just plain strings. If the system was designed today, there might be more structure in it so that the executed program could know if an argument was supposed to be an option flag or not. There are also other problems that come from the very lax structure of filenames. There's a very thorough [essay on that by dwheeler](https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html), but I have to warn that reading it is going to hurt. (Either from the detail, or from the utter awfulness of what can go wrong.)

Comment: I can't resist, you've sold it to me, I'm off to read it now, with memories of the time I managed to get a carriage return character at the end of lots of filenames (trying to see if I could construct a Windows batch file that can also run as a bash script...I didn't see that one coming!)

Answer (score 18):

Leaving aside shell behavior,let's focus on only what `rm` and `ls` can deal with themselves. At least one case where `ls` will show what `rm` can't remove involves directory permissions, and the other - special directories `.` and `..`.

#### Folder permissions

`rm` is an operation on a directory, because by removing a file, you're changing directory contents ( or in other words listing of directory entries,since d[irectory is nothing more than a list of filenames and inodes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073802/what-are-directories-if-everything-on-linux-is-a-file)). This means you need write permissions on a directory. [Even if you are the owner of the file](https://superuser.com/a/373119/418028), without directory permissions you can't remove files. The [reverse is also true](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226563/85039): `rm` can remove files that may be owned by others, if you are directory owner.

So you may very well have read and execute permissions on a directory, which will allow you traverse the directory and view contents within just fine, for example  `ls /bin/echo`, but you can't `rm /bin/echo` unless you are the owner of `/bin`  or elevate your privileges with `sudo`.

And you'll see cases like this everywhere. Here's one such case: https://superuser.com/a/331124/418028

---

#### Special directories '.' and '..'

Another special case is `.` and `..` directories. If you do `ls .` or `ls ..` , it will happily show you the contents, but `rm`'ing them is not allowed:

```
$ rm -rf .
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'
```

Answer (score 15):

If you type `ls *` and then `rm *`, it's possible you'll remove more files than `ls` showed - they might have been created in the tiny time interval between the end of `ls` and start of `rm`.

Comment: That's a probable case for `/tmp`, where many applications  can create temporary files, so that's always a possibility in both commands with `*`. However, some applications also make files anonymous by `unlink()` ing them while keeping file handle open, so it may show in `ls *` but `rm *` may  not  catch it.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy if it's been unlinked then `ls` won't show it either.

Comment: @OrangeDog You're missing the point. We're talking about  race condition

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy but that race condition is of no concern - you tried to delete it but now it's gone... so success.

Comment: @OrangeDog  It is kinda of concern as far as OPs question goes. `rm` will throw an error that file doesn't exist, so it is a case where `ls` may show it, but `rm` won't be able to find it.  Directly addresses the question.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy `rm *` won't though, unless that was the only file in there.

Comment: @OrangeDog I'll need to verify this since I'm on the phone right now, but the point still stands even with `*` there's difference between what `ls` would show and what `rm` operates on, because listing of directory contents has changed in between.

Comment: Even if you only do one command, there’s a race condition between expanding the arguments and then deleting them.

Comment: @OrangeDog I can agree with that. As  wildcard expansion works on existing filenames, yes, there's a race condition between shell expanding the wildcard, and a command processing it, so `ls *` could in fact show filename that already is gone.

Answer (score 9):

`ls *` and `rm *` are not responsible for expanding the glob - that's done by the shell before passing it to the command.

This means that you can use *any* command with the expanded filelist - so I would use something that does as little as possible.

So a better way to do this (or at the least, another way) is to skip the middle-man.

`echo *` will show you exactly what would be passed to your `rm` command.

Comment: Thank you, I like the idea of using echo instead of ls in this scenario.

Comment: Or `printf "%s\n" *` to get an unambiguous view on filenames with spaces. (Or `%q` instead to deal with newlines and control characters too, at the expense of uglier output.)

Answer (score 4):

If you do only `ls` instead of `ls -a`, yes `rm` can remove hidden files you haven't seen with `ls` without `-a`.

**Example :**

According to :

```
dir_test
├── .test
└── test2
```

`ls dir_test` : will display only test2

`ls -A dir_test` : will display test2 + .test

`rm -r dir_test` : will remove all (.test + test2)

I hope that will help you.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Because normally, `rm *` won't remove dotfiles. If it does, `ls *` will also show them.

Comment: No, `ls *` don't display hidden files.

Comment: But yes it's a little bit confused, I added some examples.

Comment: ``ls -a`` will list `.`, `..`, `.test` and `test2`.  You might want to change your example to use ``ls -A``, which list everything *except* `.` and `..` (i.e., only `.test` and `test2`).

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
$ mkdir what
$ cd what
$ mkdir -p huh/uhm ./-r
$ ls *
uhm
$ rm *
$ ls
-r
$ ls -R
.:
-r

./-r:
```

Basically wildcards expanding to stuff starting with `-` (or manually entered stuff starting with `-` but that looks a bit more like cheating) may be interpreted differently by `ls` and `rm`.

Answer (score 4):

There *are* edge cases where what `ls` shows is not what `rm` removes. A rather extreme, but fortunately benign one is if the argument you pass is a symbolic link to a directory: `ls` will show you all the files in the symlinked directory, while `rm` will remove the symlink, leaving the original directory and its contents untouched:

```
% ln -s $HOME some_link
% ls some_link    # Will display directory contents  
bin    lib    Desktop ...
% rm some_link
% ls $HOME
bin    lib    Desktop ...
```

Comment: Huh. `ln -s $HOME some_link; ls some_link` outputs `some_link@` for me, but I have `ls` aliased to `ls -F`. Apparently, `-F` changes the behaviour to showing the link instead of dereferencing it. Did not expect that.

Comment: Indeed! Also `ls -l` for example targets the link, not the destination... there have to be ways to inspect the link itself.

Comment: Adding options to the question opens up too many possibilities-- my answer is about the unmodified behavior of `ls` and `rm`.

Comment: If you say `ls some_link/`, `ls -H some_link`, or `ls -L some_link`, it will list the linked-to directory, even if you add `-F` or `-l`.  Conversely (sort-of), `-d` says to look at a directory rather than its contents; compare `ls -l /tmp` and `ls -ld /tmp`.

Comment: Sure, you can add flags that change the behavior of `ls`. You're basically showing why enumerating behaviors with different flags is not worth the bother for this question...

Answer (score 3):

There are already many good answers, but I want to add some more deep insight.

Ask yourself the question: How many parameters are passed to `ls`, if you write

```
ls *
```

...? Note that the `ls` command does not get the `*` as parameter if there are any files that `*` can be expanded to. Instead, the shell first performs globbing before invoking the command, so the `ls` command actually gets as many parameters as there are files matched by the globbing. To suppress globbing, quote the parameter.

This is true for any command: `echo *` vs `echo '*'`.

There is a script, call it `countparams.sh` to test the effect. It tells you how many parameters it got passed and lists them.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This script was given $# parameters."
arr=( "$@" )
for ((i=0;i<$#;i++)); do
        echo "Parameter $((i+1)): ${arr[$i]}"
done
```

Make it executable and run `./countparams.sh *`. Learn from its output!

Answer (score 1):

The glob will expand the same way both times, *if* the directory contents are the same at those two different times.

---

If you really want to check what will be removed, use `rm -i  *.txt`.  It will prompt you separately for each file before (trying to) remove it.

This is guaranteed to be safe against race conditions:
        `ls *.txt` / a new file is created / `rm *.txt`
because you're prompted for every file by the same program that's doing the removal.

---

This is too cumbersome for normal use, and if you alias `rm` to `rm -i`, you'll find yourself using `\rm` or `rm -f` fairly often.  But it is worth at least mentioning that there is a solution to the race condition.  (It's even portable to non-GNU systems: [POSIX `rm(1)` specifies the `-i` option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/rm.html).)

Another option would be a bash array: `to_remove=(*.txt)`, then ask the user to confirm (perhaps after doing `ls -ld -- "${to_remove[@]}"`), then
`rm -- "${to_remove[@]}"`.  So glob expansion is only done once, and the list is passed verbatim to `rm`.

Another practically-usable option is GNU `rm -I` ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html)), which prompts if removing more than 4 items.  (But doesn't show you the list, just the total.)  I use `alias rm='rm -I'` on my desktop.

It's a nice safeguard against fat-fingering return with a half-typed pattern that matches too much.  But using `ls` first is generally good in a directory you own, or on a single-user system, and when there aren't background processes that could asynchronously create new files there.  To guard against fat-fingering, don't type `rm -rf /foo/bar/baz` from left to right.  `rm -rf /` is special-cased, but `rm -rf /usr` isn't!  Leave out the `-rf` part, or start with `ls`, and only add the `rm -rf` part after typing the path.