# Display a text message when running a specific command

Tags: command-line

Sometimes, after I run some commands (for example `git` commands), I discover that I forgot some configurations or forgot to put some requirements... . So I thought about displaying a message, to remind me or warn me, (like the one displayed when we run `sudo apt upgrade`:

> The following packages will be upgraded ... Do you want to continue [Y/n]?)

I want to get a similar message when I run a specific command ("*Did you check the conf files, did you update the requirements file?*) When I type **Y**, the command run and when I type **n**, the command stops.
How to do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, when there are things that have to be done before an actual command runs - such as providing and setting up environment variables, adding extra positional parameters, etc - the command is placed into a wrapper script. How it should be implemented - that depends on the specific command you want and things you want to check before actual command runs. In the very simple case such as `git`, you could do something along the following lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

printf "%s\n" "Did you check the conf files, did you update the requirements file?[y/n]"
read answer

case "$answer" in
    [Yy])  exec git commit -a ;;
    [Nn]) printf "%s\n" "Please check. Exiting"; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Of course the next question is the naming of the command. This script could be named `git-commit` or something similar. I would advice against naming wrapper scripts same as the original application.

See also:

- [In Bash, how to add “Are you sure [Y/n]” to any command or alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3231804/3701431)
- [Add flag to existing terminal command](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073443/295286)

Comment: +1 nice touch adding references to sister-site. I would note best to use "Y" to proceed, any other key to exit. Currently if user presses "U" neither "Y" nor "N" is executed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Agreed, that's a better approach. I'll try to remember that for the future